# Getting latest value from database, checking value and applying itself in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP so am not sure if I'm doing this right but can someone give it a second pair of eyes for me please?

Basically what I want it is that we can define an initial start of an invoice number, in this example 00001 - if that is not found in the invoices table on latest entry then show 00001 else I need it to take the latest and add 1 onto the value to display when creating the next invoice.

I guess it will need a condition so that if the actual table is empty as well as if no result to start at 00001

PHP so far

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="invoice_id" value="AMBMN<?php getInvoiceId(); ?>">
```

PHP:

```
// Initial invoice number
function getInvoiceId() {

    define('INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE', '00001');

    // Connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

    // output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT invoice FROM invoices ORDER BY invoice DESC LIMIT 1";

    // mysqli select query
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    //Invoice length
    $invoice = $row['invoice'];

    if(!$result){
        echo INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE;
    } else {
    // check if the initial invoice ID has already been used and if not start from that value else from the next value
        if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
            echo $invoice;
        } else {
            echo INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE;
        }
    }

    // Frees the memory associated with a result
    $result->free();

    // close connection 
    $mysqli->close();

}
```

Comment: Seems fine, is there a problem? Oh, there is one issue, you have if(!$result == INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) but instead of !$result ==, it should be if($result != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) - although I think you want to check if it IS the same? So keep what you have and remove the !

Comment: Ahh getting my JS and PHP mixed up, i changed and updated question with else as well but its breaking page on the value="" part plus just showing the number 1 not 00001 - like this:  value="AMBMN1 < no html after this, breaking from that point.

Comment: I posted an answer with the code to fix the 0s, so it will fix that, lemme know how it goes. Is it still breaking?

Comment: If the invoice number can be entered by any user, and you're wanting to see if it has already been used, surely you want to check all of the records and not only the last one? Otherwise they could enter one that's in the middle and it'll overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to count the row for the condition to work and also as above set the result as a variable. see below:

```
// Connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

    // output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT invoice FROM invoices ORDER BY invoice DESC LIMIT 1";

    // mysqli select query
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    // get number of returned results, if 0 action it below
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    //Invoice length
    $invoice = $row['invoice'];

    if($row_cnt == "0"){
        echo INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE;
    } else {
        // check if the initial invoice ID has already been used and if not start from that value else from the next value
        if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
            echo ++$invoice;
        }
    }

    // Frees the memory associated with a result
    $result->free();

    // close connection 
    $mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the results from the query, create a variable for the invoice number and you can do this:

```html
//Invoice number
define('INVOICE', '00001');

//Invoice length
$invoice_len = strlen(INVOICE);

//sprintf formatting string
$spf_format = '%0' . $invoice_len . 'd';

//Replace the 5 in %05d with however many characters there will be. 
//In your case there are 5.
//It is now formatted with the 0s at the start.
$invoice = sprintf($spf_format, INVOICE);

echo $invoice;
```

When you say it breaks from that point, do you mean it stops completely? Or does it show the closing tags too?

While I'm here I might as well explain what the '%05d' is doing, inside sprintf.

The sprintf command is used to change the formatting of a variable. The % at the start is merely the beginning of the definition, it is always present. 0 means that the number following it is going to control the exact length of the variable. So we set it to 5, as there are 5 characters and it's highly unlikely to reach 6 with this format, but if it does then you can work around that fairly easily. So that's the %05 - now the d at the end basically tells PHP to treat the variable as an integer, but display it as a signed decimal (signed meaning it can be negative).

All in all what it's doing is telling PHP to treat that variable as a 5 character long integer and display it as a decimal, so that all of the 0s stay present.

Comment: Problem there is that it comes from the define which will be set by the user so could be anything, even it 7263 or 120 or any number and yea its breaking after the function on frontend and not closing the tag so its like blah="dfdsdsds << not closing " and nothing after.

Comment: So the invoice number can be 2, but it can also be 00002?

Comment: Does it stop breaking if you remove the last two lines? the free/close ones.

Comment: noticed it was $results->free(); and not $result->free(); its showing as 1 rather than whats set in CONSTANT

Comment: Ah yeah and as the other guy said, $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); first, and use $row, not $result

Comment: i done //Invoice length
 $invoice_len = strlen($result);

 //sprintf formatting string
 $spf_format = '%0' . $invoice_len . 'd';

 //It is now formatted with the 0s at the start.
 $invoice = sprintf($spf_format, $row['invoice']);

Comment: Ahh its showing 1 as have that +1 so not returning anything, there is no data in the database so what can i do if not data? ive updated main question with code i have so far with attempt if no result else etc... so if no result to use default CONSTANT value set in config, if result and number whats returned matches 00001 to use next one up +1 so 00002 for example

Comment: if($row = $result->fetch_array()){//code}else{//This means it is empty}

Comment: I managed to sort it, ill add solution - thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code,  firstly I can see `$result =mysqli->query()`  the `$result` here is a mysqli object and cannot be compared with the constant. Please  get the values of the object first then do the comparative.